# Import Error when using cx_freeze with pythoncom

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have made a simple keylogger program in python. The program works perfectly with Python Interpreter. Then, I converted it into an executable using cx_freeze.

[image: The Build Folder:]

The problem now is that there are import errors.

[image: The Error Shown:]

I can't find the relevant .pyd files for pythoncom and pywintypes. So, where can I find these files? The surprising thing is that when I copy and paste pythoncom.py and pywintypes.py into the folder, the executable works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was discovered after the release of cx_Freeze 5.0 and has since been resolved in the source. A new release will be made in the next week or two but in the meantime you can simply copy the file cx_Freeze/hooks.py from the source to your installation. The source can be found here:

https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/src/

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. The executable now works perfectly fine.