# cx_Freeze 5.0: ImportError: No module named 'scipy.__config__'

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, scipy, cx-freeze

## Problem

I get the following error when trying to run an .exe built with cx_Freeze:

```
File
"C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__py", line 105 in <module>
  from scipy.__config__ import show as show_config
ImportError: No module named 'scipy.__config__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
File
"C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__py", line 105 in <module>
   raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Error importing scipy: you cannot import scipy while being in scipy source directory; please exit the scipy source tree first, and relaunch your python interpreter.
```

How could I troubleshoot this?

[image: Screenshot from the error message]

## Additional Information

### Setup

- Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit
- WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5 (Python 3.5.2 64-bit)
- cx_Freeze 5.0 (*)
- scipy 0.18.1

(*) With [pythoncom fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744692/import-error-when-using-cx-freeze-with-pythoncom) in the hooks.py

### setup.py:

```
import os
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\tcl\tcl8.6" 
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\tcl\tk8.6" 


base = 'Console'
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'excludes': ['gtk', 'PyQt4', 'Tkinter'],
    }
}


executables = [
    Executable('GUI.py', base=base)
]


setup(name='GUI',
      version='0.1',
      description='GUI test',
      executables=executables,
      options=options
      )
```

### Errors during build

None.

## What else have I tried?

1) Tried to add `'includes': ['scipy.__config__']` to the setup.py.

- Result: error during build `ImportError: No module named 'scipy.__config__'`

2) Tried to add `'packages': ['scipy'],` to the setup.py.

- Result: error during build `ImportError: No module named 'scipy'`

3) Renamed the `finder.IncludePackage("scipy.lib")` in the  `cx_Freeze/hooks.py` to `finder.IncludePackage("scipy._lib")` as instructed in the answer of the SO Question "[Cx_freeze ImportError no module named scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432887/cx-freeze-importerror-no-module-named-scipy)" + added `'packages': ['scipy'],` to the setup.py.

- Result: No build-time errors. When trying to run the .exe, it gives `ImportError: No module named 'scipy.spatial.ckdtree'`
- Tried also with `'includes': ['scipy.spatial.ckdtree']` in the `setup.py`, but the problem persists.
- The build output has the following lines:

  `m scipy.spatial.cKDTree     C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\cKDTree.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
  m scipy.spatial.ckdtree     C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\ckdtree.cp35-win_amd64.pyd`

Comment: Ok so seems that the problem was solved in step 3) of "What else have I tried?". The `ImportError: No module named 'scipy.spatial.ckdtree'`-error was caused by the `seaborn` package, and troubleshooting that would be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution (not the greatest but it works). Go to the `scipy\spatial` directory (within the `build` directory) and change the file from `cKDTree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` to `ckdtree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`.

NOTE: your file name might be slightly different depending which python version but the main thing is to use lowercase `kdt` in the file name.

The capital letters is the problem. It worked for me.