# cx_Freeze and seaborn - ImportError: No module named 'scipy.spatial.ckdtree'

Tags: python, windows, scipy, seaborn, cx-freeze

## Problem

For some reason when importing the `seaborn` package, and making an executable (.exe) will give following ImportError. How to troubleshoot this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Fr
eeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 12, in <module>
    __import__(name + "__init__")
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Fr
eeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 21, in <module>
    scriptModule = __import__(moduleName)
  File "GUI.py", line 22, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\seabo
rn\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .linearmodels import *
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\seabo
rn\linearmodels.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial import distance
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy
\spatial\__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
    from .ckdtree import *
ImportError: No module named 'scipy.spatial.ckdtree'
```

## Additional Information

### Setup

- Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit
- WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5 (Python 3.5.2 64-bit)
- cx_Freeze 5.0
- scipy 0.18.1

  Renamed the `finder.IncludePackage("scipy.lib")` in the  `cx_Freeze/hooks.py` to `finder.IncludePackage("scipy._lib")` as instructed in the answer of the SO Question "[Cx_freeze ImportError no module named scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432887/cx-freeze-importerror-no-module-named-scipy)"

### setup.py:

```
import os
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\tcl\tcl8.6" 
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3Qt5\python-3.5.2.amd64\tcl\tk8.6" 

base = None

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'excludes': ['gtk', 'PyQt4', 'Tkinter'],
        'packages': ['scipy'],
        'includes': ['scipy.spatial.ckdtree'],
    }
}


executables = [
    Executable('GUI.py', base=base)
]



setup(name='GUI',
      version='0.1',
      description='GUI test',
      executables=executables,
      options=options
      )
```

Comment: See also a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40975758/cx-freeze-5-0-importerror-no-module-named-scipy-config

Answer (score 6):

Try renaming `cKDTree.cp35-win_amd64.pyd`  to `ckdtree.cp35-win_amd64.pyd`. This works for my case.

The file shoudld be under your build path, such as `build\exe.win-amd64-3.5\scipy\spatial\`.